# Best way to have 2 connections to sql server (one read one write)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a very large number of rows (10 million) which I need to select out of a SQL Server table. I will go through each record and parse out each one (they are xml), and then write each one back to a database via a stored procedure.

The question I have is, what's the most efficient way to do this?

The way I am doing it currently is I open 2 `SqlConnection`'s (one for read one for write).  The read one uses the `SqlDataReader` of which it basically does a `select * from table` and I loop through the dataset. After I parse each record I do an `ExecuteNonQuery` (using parameters) on the second connection.

Is there any suggestions to make this more efficient, or is this just the way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: You can't do the update in the SP? Then you wouldn't need to select anything. Otherwise the most efficient way is to load all into a `DataTable`, loop all rows in memory, set the new value and write all back to the database via [`SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(table)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: If you have SQL Server 2012 you could look at [Always On Availability Groups](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa427606-8422-4656-b205-c9e665ddc8c1) specifically Readable Secondary Replicas

Comment: in what ways are you parsing the data? From what i gathered, youre downloading xml files and then parse the file, and then upload the parsed fields into sql again? IF youre doing it that way, i would say the best way to go through that is to do it all on sql, and yes it is possible to cycle through and parse xml content in sql.

Comment: I already have a process which runs on SQL to parse everything, but it runs slow and I'm limited to what I can do within transact sql.  C# parses XML much faster than SQL and I have more functionality available, rather than having to call CLR functions to do what I need.

Comment: What are you doing with the parse? Are you modifying the data before you write it back? Why do you need two tables?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are writing rows one-by-one. That is the slowest possible model. [Write bigger batches.](https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en#complete=1&hl=en&q=sql%20server%20mass%20update)

There is no need for two connections when you use MARS. Unfortunately, MARS forces a 14 byte row versioning tag in each written row. Might be totally acceptable, or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had very slimier situation and here what I did:

1. I made two copies of same database.
2. One is optimized for reading and another is optimized for writing.
3. In config, i kept two connection string ConnectionRead and ConnectionWrite.
4. Now in DataLayer when I have read statement(select..) I switch my connection to ConnectionRead connection string and when writing using other one.

Now since I have to keep both the databases in sync, I am using SQL replication for this job.

I can understand implementation depends on many aspect but approach may help you.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Tim Schmelter's post - I did something very similar... I actually used a SQLCLR procedure which read the data from a XML column in a SQL table into an in-memory (table) using .net (System.Data) then used the .net System.Xml namespace to deserialize the xml, populated another in-memory table (in the shape of the destination table) and used the sqlbulkcopy to populate that destination SQL table with those parsed attributes I needed.

SQL Server is engineered for set-based operations... If ever I'm shredding/iterating (row-by-row) I tend to use SQLCLR as .Net is generally better at iterative/data-manipulative processing.  An exception to my rule is when working with a little metadata for data-driven processes, cleanup routines where I may use a cursor.

Comment: This really should be a comment instead of an answer.